# Resize the HTML Modal during runtime using GAS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a modal displaying a html form. The form has a button.
Modal is set to a width of 600x425 initially. Then during runtime, if the button is pressed it should resize the modal from 600x425 to 300x200.

How do I get this using google apps script

```
function showPickerImages() {

        var html = HtmlService
            .createTemplateFromFile("MyHTMLForm")
            .evaluate()
            .addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
            .setWidth(600)
            .setHeight(425)
            .setTitle("Resize demo")
            .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'demo');
}
```

MyHTMLForm.html

```
<button onclick="resizeModalDialog()"></button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`google.script.host.setWidth(width)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#setWidth(Integer)) and [`setHeight`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#setheightheight):

```
// resize modal window
function resizeModalDialog()
{
  google.script.host.setWidth(300);
  google.script.host.setHeight(200);
}
```